# Umount and mount a mount point on a host machine from docker container

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker-compose, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

Hi I'm having an issue with how to umount and mount a mount point from a docker container. I have a python programm that I run inside it and I use subprocess library to execute commands.

The code is like this.

```
 def mount_partition(mount_point):
            try:
                subprocess.run(['sudo /bin/mount',mount_point], timeout=10)
                logging.debug("{mount_point} remounted.")                             
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                logging.info(f'Failed to execute command MOUNT on {mount_point}')
```

Inside the docker compose I tried to bind the volume like this

```
volumes:
      - "/mnt/volume1:/mnt/volume1"
```

My question is how could I execute the subprocess command on the host machine and not inside the container ? or how could I point it to look at the host machine not inside the container ?

to test the code I unmounted it manually to see if the program would mount it again but it's not working as the container is still shown as mounted ( I kind of expected it since i created the volume inside)